Diameter bounds by mean curvature and area
I'm wondering about a generalization of Simon/Topping/Wu-Zheng's results on bounding diameter by the mean curvature, which roughly says: given a closed $\Sigma^{n-1} \subseteq M^n$,
$$\text{diam}(\Sigma) \leq C \int_{\Sigma} |H_{\Sigma}|^{n-1}$$
In all of the previous results, $M$ is either euclidean space, or a space with restrictions on sectional curvature. I'm wondering if a more general inequality of the form
$$\text{diam}(\Sigma) \leq C \int_{\Sigma} |H_{\Sigma}|^{n-1} + F(\mathcal{H}^{n-1}(\Sigma))$$
holds? $M$ can be either compact or non-compact, but the extra constant must be there to allow for minimal surfaces. Diameter either intrinsic or extrinsic. Any sources on, or ideas towards this are appreciated!

Do you want the diameter to be intrinsic or extrinsic? And by the volume of $\Sigma$ do you mean the $(n-1)$-dimensional Hausdorff measure, or some kind of enclosed volume?

either intrinsic or extrinsic. And yes, the n-1 hausdorff measure. So area for $\Sigma^2 \subseteq M^3$
